# Json parsing nil field in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have a problem with mapping a JSON to a foundation object...

Is there any way to put a "nil" value to a class member variable when the JSON string doesn't contain that key?

Ex, here's my DataModel class:

```
@interface DataModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* Status;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* ErrorCode;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ClientModel* Client;

@end
```

That class is used to parse some information about the client in the ClientModel object and has a ErrorCode & Status field.

Status field can contains either "Ok" or "Error". No problem here. the next field is an ErrorCode in case the json contained "Error" as the status.

The problem is that the server won't always send me a key-value for ErrorCode (When the Status is "Ok", the server API doesn't send the ErrorCode key-value).

Considering the fact that I cannot modify the JSON sent by the server, how can parse the JSON string received in my modal object and put "nil" as the ErrorCode value when the JSON string doesn't contain it?

Is there any library that allow us to do this? I'm currently using JSONModel, but it gives me an "Incoming data was invalid" error when keys are missing. I know Jackson API for java handle this kind of situation, but I'm not aware if there's something like that in Objective-C. If I can do a workaround with NSJSONSerialization I would be glad to hear it, too.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you populating the model? Are you pulling values out of an `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like JSONModel declares [a protocol called "Optional"](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModel/JSONModel.h#L32) which is intended for exactly this use. Declare the property that might not be present in the JSON as conforming to this protocol to make the initializer not error:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> * ErrorCode;
```

Comment: Thank you Josh! Couldn't have been more simple. Another question, how do I apply that protocol for an NSArray? Xcode confuses it as a class name since it has the same characters '<' '>' !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The property declaration should look the same no matter what the class: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Optional> * baubles;`

Comment: Oh, I think I didn't declared my NSArray the proper way.. Coming from a Java background we had to specify the type of object that would be contained in the array! Thanks again for your time Josh.

Comment: Actually, wait! I just read again the small tutorials here: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/JSONModel/#cascade... How can I add the <Optional> protocol to this property?? @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<TweetModel>* tweets;

Comment: Multiple protocols all go between the angle brackets, separated by commas: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Optional, TweetModel>* tweets;`

Comment: What happens to the primitive properties? for example @property (assign) BOOL isPlaying;

Comment: Just figure out how to handle that case with the method:


+(BOOL)propertyIsOptional:(NSString *)propertyName;